# Как изменить значение DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть DropDown:

```
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        Уровень риска:
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRiskLevel" runat="server" Enabled ="false">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Низкий" Value="1" Selected="true"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Высокий" Value="2" />
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
```

При открытии страницы у DropDown по умолчанию `Низкий`
Нужно при открытии той части страницы где dropdown , при выполнении условии DropDownList изменился на `Высокий`
В `Page_PreRender` пытался(не меняется) :

```
 if (Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox_Premia.Text) >= 1000000)
 {
    ddlRiskLevel.SelectedValue = "2";
 }
```

Где нужно прописать, мб в UpdatePanel
Всем спасибо решено, прописал в Page_Load, DropDown поместил в UpdatePanel,свойство UpdateMode="always"

Comment: У вас же Selected="true" стоит для первого элемента. Уберите и поставьте на второй

Comment: @koks_rs, но тогда 2-й элемент будет всегда True, мне нужно чтобы менялся в зависимости условии

Comment: попробуйте тогда ваш код  в Page_Load выполнить

Comment: @koks_rs, с условием не получается

Comment: @ну тогда разберитесь что у Вас TextBox_Premia.Text и почему он пустой. Может быть Вы его в Page_Load очищаете

Comment: @koks_rs, ну это я к примеру вообще при условии вопрос изменил

Answer (score 1):

```
ddlRiskLevel.ClearSelection(); // Убедитесь, что предыдущее выделение было очищено
ddlRiskLevel.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

Comment: не получается, а с условием и где нужно прописать

Comment: как вам уже тут писали в методе Page_Load, на загрузку страницы